# Python vectorization vs Julia for loops

Tags: python-3.x, optimization, julia, vectorization

There are a lot of posts regarding the speed vectorized versus devectorized code in Julia, but my question regards a very simple piece of code that I ran in Python and Julia to compare performance. I have a huge Python code that I will transcribe to Julia if and only if functions like this one are significantly sped up.

I am running everything in Jupyter notebooks and I know that Julia runs faster in a .jl file; however, I compared with running from the terminal and the difference in this case is rather negligible.

The Python code uses broadcasting and vectorization:

```
def test(x0,dx,i):
   q = np.arange(-x0,x0,dx)  
   z = np.zeros(shape=(i,len(q)), dtype=np.complex128)
   B = np.exp(-1j*q)

   for s in range(1,i):
      A = np.exp(-(q-q[:,np.newaxis])**2)*np.exp(-1j*s*q)
      z[s] = B*np.sum(A,axis=1)*dx

   return z
```

while in the Julia translation I attempted to use for loops, but ended up using comprehension once, since it was faster than another for loop::

```
function test(x0,dx,n)
    z = zeros(ComplexF64, (n, Int(2*x0/dx + 1)))
    B = exp.(-1im*(-x0:dx:x0-dx))

    for s in 1:n-1
        for (i,q) in enumerate(-x0:dx:x0-dx)    
            A = [exp(-(q-Q)^2)exp(-1im*s*Q) for Q in -x0:dx:x0-dx]
            z[s,i] = B[i]*sum(A)*dx
        end       
    end   
    z
end
```

The results are

```
%timeit test(10,.1,10)
```

> > 2.81 ms ± 247 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
@btime test(10,.1,10)
```

> > 55.075 ms (2176212 allocations: 61.20 MiB)

That is, the Julia code is much slower. I'm absolutely sure I'm doing something wrong here, since the allocations shouldn't be that huge. I tried to optimize this as much as I could, but I started learning Julia a couple of days ago and couldn't go much further. Any tips on how to improve performance here is hugely appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

There were several things initially holding this back: The first and biggest was the loop comprehension which was allocating a ton as you correctly diagnosed (16ms). Once that was solved, the biggest issue was the way it was repeatedly computing the same complex exponents (1.6 ms).

Once both of those issues were addressed, recognizing the linear algebra in the problem allowed both cleaner code, and also allowed julia to call into blas to do more efficient matrix multiplication. (900 μs). Here is the most updated code that is about a factor of 3 better than the equivalent numpy

```
using LinearAlgebra
function test(x0,dx,n)
    Q = collect(-x0:dx:x0-dx)
    A = complex.(exp.(-(Q.-transpose(Q)).^2))
    B = exp.(-im.*transpose(1:n-1).*Q)
    z = Matrix{ComplexF64}(undef, n-1, length(Q))
    for (i, q) in enumerate(Q)
        total = transpose(@view A[:, i]) * B
        z[:, i] = dx*exp(-q*im) .* total
    end
    z
end
```

In response to the numba attempt, here is one more attempt that gets down to 725μs by working around a bug where multiplying real and complex arrays would convert the real to a complex. Manually coding the multiplication yields this.

```
function test(x0,dx,n)
    Q = collect(-x0:dx:x0-dx)
    A = exp.(-(Q.-transpose(Q)).^2)
    B = exp.(-im.*transpose(1:n-1).*Q)
    rB = real.(B)
    iB = imag.(B)
    z = Matrix{ComplexF64}(undef, n-1, length(Q))
    for (i, q) in enumerate(Q)
        At = transpose(@view A[:, i])
        total =  (At * rB) .+ (At * iB).*im
        z[:, i] = dx*exp(-q*im) .* total
    end
    z
end
```

Comment: Nice improvement! I'll study your solution in a while. I really hope Julia can surpass Python here.

Comment: I got it down to 1.6ms

Comment: Don't do this: `length = size(-x0:dx:x0-dx)[1]`. Do this: `N = length(-x0:dx:x0-dx)`. `length` is a built-in function, and it's better to use that then to twist it around like this.

Answer (score 3):

Just for comparison I want to add a optimized Python (Numba) solution. The solution by Oscar Smith still looks a bit slow, but this may also be the result of a slower processor.

Some comparisons, optimized Numba vs. optimized Julia code are really good to learn how to write efficient code in Julia.

**Code**

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb

def Test_orig(x0,dx,i):
    q = np.arange(-x0,x0,dx)  
    z = np.zeros(shape=(i,len(q)), dtype=np.complex128)
    B = np.exp(-1j*q)

    for s in range(1,i):
        A = np.exp(-(q-q[:,np.newaxis])**2)*np.exp(-1j*s*q)
        z[s] = B*np.sum(A,axis=1)*dx

    return z

@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=True)
def Test_nb(x0,dx,n):
    q = np.arange(-x0,x0,dx)
    B = np.exp(-1j*q)
    z = np.zeros(shape=(n,q.shape[0]), dtype=np.complex128)

    TMP_1 = np.empty(shape=(q.shape[0],q.shape[0]), dtype=np.complex128)
    for i in nb.prange(q.shape[0]):
        for j in range(q.shape[0]):
            TMP_1[i,j]=np.exp(-(q[i]-q[j])**2)

    TMP_2 = np.empty(shape=(q.shape[0],q.shape[0]), dtype=np.complex128)
    for s in nb.prange(1,n):
        for j in range(q.shape[0]):
            TMP_2[s,j]=np.exp(-1j*s*q[j])

    for s in nb.prange(1,n):
        for i in range(q.shape[0]):
            sum=0.j
            for j in range(q.shape[0]):
                sum+=TMP_1[i,j]*TMP_2[s,j]
            z[s,i]=sum*B[i]*dx
    return z
```

**Timings**

```
%timeit res_1=Test_orig(10,.1,10)
2.64 ms ± 276 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
%timeit res_2=Test_nb(10,.1,10)
192 µs ± 7.06 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
#@nb.njit(fastmath=True,parallel=False,cache=True) -> single threaded, caching possible
472 µs ± 19.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
#@nb.njit(fastmath=False,parallel=False,cache=True) -> without fastmath compiler flag
643 µs ± 10.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

res_1=Test_orig(10,.1,10)
res_2=Test_nb(10,.1,10)
np.allclose(res_1,res_2)
True
```

**Edit: Julia Timings (function from Oscar Smith)**

```
@benchmark test(10,.1,10)
BenchmarkTools.Trial:
  memory estimate:  1.16 MiB
  allocs estimate:  1014
  --------------
  minimum time:     643.072 μs (0.00% GC)
  median time:      662.869 μs (0.00% GC)
  mean time:        729.127 μs (4.15% GC)
  maximum time:     34.947 ms (97.25% GC)
  --------------
  samples:          6841
  evals/sample:     1
```

Comment: So, you again made Python faster than Julia! I'm confused once again if translating my code is worth it.

Comment: Can you run my code? I'm on a 4 year old laptop, so my cpu is definitely not the strongest.

Comment: For me using eqivilent settings (Fastmath=False, parallel=False) this takes 763ms to run `Test_nb(10,.01,100)` compared to 227ms for my most recent version.

Comment: I had installed Julia a while ago and did some tries. For sure I have to try it again. My problem was to find some really good examples how to code things. Actually I did run into the same problems like the questioner.

Comment: Part of the reason I'm having trouble beating numba is that there is currently a julia performance bug where real*complex array is slower than it should be since there isn't a method for vector{real}*matrix{complex}, so it promotes the vector.

Comment: I'm really interested in the outcome of the discussion above. I have by now translated almost half of my work to Julia, and by now things are running at least 3x faster than in Python. I wasn't using Numba, though.